# How to troubleshoot MATLAB code that returns incorrect results

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement

I am at an absolute loss with this function. It's written in MATLAB and it's supposed to give the optimal alignment of DNA-sequences based on a Needleman-Wunsch matrix. Which isn't that relevant, because as far as I can tell that doesn't have to do with the issue.

I don't understand where it keeps going wrong, because it seems to just be making some kind of calculation mistake and I know that isn't possible.

This is the function. I know it's not very efficient but I thought at least it should work:

```
function [q1, q2, w] = traceback(D, seq1, seq2, g, S)
lengte = max(length(seq1), length(seq2));       % Preallocatie Q1 en Q2
q1 = char([]);                         
q2 = char([]);
w = D(length(seq1)+1,length(seq2)+1);           % Bepaling w (laatste element van matrix D)
a = 0;
b = 0;
k = 0;
for i = length(seq1):-1:2
    for j = length(seq2):-1:2
        if D(i,j) == D(i,j-1) - g               % Naar links = gap in seq1
            q1 = ['-', q1];
            q2 = [seq2(end-b), q2];
            b = b+1;
            k = k+1;           
        elseif D(i,j) == D(i-1,j) - g           % Naar boven = gap in seq2
            q1 = [seq1(end-a), q1];
            q2 = ['-', q2];
            a = a+1;
            k = k+1;
        else                                    % Linksboven = match/puntmutatie
            q1 = [seq1(end-a), q1];
            q2 = [seq2(end-b), q2];
            a = a+1;
            b = b+1;
            k = k+1;
        end
        if k == lengte
            return
        end
            
    end
end
```

**These are the variables put into it:**

```
seq1 = 'CGT';
seq2 = 'ACGT';
g = -5;
S = [10 -1 -3 -4; -1 7 -5 -3; -3 -5 9 0; -4 -3 0 8];
D =

     0    -5   -10   -15   -20
    -5    -3     4    -1    -6
   -10    -6    -1    11     6
   -15   -11    -6     6    19
```

(D is calculated with another function that does definitely work)

**This is what I get:**

```
q1 = 'CG-T'
q2 = 'ACGT'
w = 19
```

**This is what I'm supposed to get:**

```
q1 = '-CGT'
q2 = 'ACGT'
w = 19
```

So it seems to be going wrong at the first `if-statement` during the second iteration of the `for-loop`s:

```
if D(i,j) == D(i,j-1) - g               % Naar links = gap in seq1
```

Which at this point should translate to D(2,3) == D(2,2) - g, which translates to 4 == -3 + 5, which is obviously incorrect, so I don't understand why it executes that `if`.

Comment: You should learn to use the debugger. That is the way to see what the program does, which branches it takes, what the variable values are at each step, etc. See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html

Answer (score 0):

The comment is correct, using the debugger you will be able to see the problem easier, as well as have a better time solving future problems. Now, to combine this with an answer to your question, let's see how we would go about it in this case.

First, you put a breakpoint (the little red dot before the line) on the line where you think the problem is, in this case the if statement on line 11 of the traceback function. Now, you run the function with the given parameters. Because of the breakpoint, it will pause on the if statement. Now, because you think the problem is on the second iteration, you click "continue" in the editor tab of the Matlab IDE. This will continue the script until it again reaches the if statement.

We can now see if what you think should be the situation at this point is the actual situation. If I do this, I do not get D(2,3) == D(2,2) - g, as you assumed in your question, but rather D(3,3) == D(3,2) - g. This adds a "-" to the q1 variable where you do not want it. We found the bug!

Now starts the process of identifying where things go wrong or unexpected. I am sure you will do better here than me, as you're familiar with the algorithm. Good luck!